# seek to time in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, avqueueplayer

Can any one help me to seek at particular time in `AVQueuePlayer`?

I have use this controller to play video in iPhone because i need to play two video at the same time.
But my problem is to navigate in video and jump to at particular time, I am not able to do that.

I Know the method the That is `[controller seekToTime:(CMTime)]` But it is not moving the video at exact position of the video.

Does any one know the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is stated in the documentation for `seekToTime:`:

> The time seeked to may differ from the specified time for efficiency. For sample accurate seeking see `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:`.

So try using `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:` instead, specifying a low or zero tolerance. You may also want to specify true for `AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey` when creating any AVURLAssets you may be using.

Answer (score 1):

> Update... I ended up doing hackery and not being especially pleased with the results--the snap-through-black between movies may or may not show, and because I was bad and didn't inquire as to the load status etc it's possible to get many things confused.
>
> But for straight looping an AVQueuePlayer assetItem it works to set a boundaryTime observer and use that to rewind the assetItem. My stuff is only a few seconds long so the seekToTime is pretty seamless, I don't know what it'll do seeking on a longer asset. [looping an assetItem in AVQueuePlayer](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/73769-looping-assetitem-avqueueplayer.html)